# db2 error in dataview SQL0956C

Tags: sql, db2

I am receiving this error on DB2 9.7.8

```
Database handling error - 4003: Database error in dataview MATCHTAB: SQL0956C  Not enough storage is available in the database heap to process the statement.
```

I have already increased the Heap size as recommended here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00956c.html?lang=en

but it hasn't resolved the error.
I increased the heapsize from 6000 to 8000.

Is there any way to determine the appropriate heapsize as I do not want to increase it arbitrarily?

Thanks,

Joe

db2diag log at mustaccios suggestion

```
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Out of memory failure for Database Heap (DBHEAP) on node 0.
Requested block size           : 8208 bytes.
Physical heap size             : 48955392 bytes.
Configured heap size           : 49872896 bytes.
Unreserved memory used by heap : 0 bytes.
Unreserved memory left in set  : 61014016 bytes.

2014-01-20-15.16.30.573000+060 I90041446H637      LEVEL: Error
PID     : 2504                 TID  : 2488        PROC : db2syscs.exe
INSTANCE: DB2                  NODE : 000         DB   : Database1
APPHDL  : 0-4062               APPID: *LOCAL.DB2.140120140000
AUTHID  : CORONA  
EDUID   : 2488                 EDUNAME: db2agent (CORONA) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, access plan manager, sqlra_add_pkg_id_to_ejected_list, probe:252
RETCODE : ZRC=0x8B0F0002=-1961951230=SQLO_NOMEM_DBH
      "No memory available in 'Database Heap'"
      DIA8302C No memory available in the database heap.
DATA #1 : signed integer, 8 bytes
7360
```

Comment: Check the instance diagnostic log (`db2diag.log`) -- it may list the amount of memory that was actually requested.

Comment: Is this a 32-bit installation? If so, there's a good chance that you're over-allocating DB2 memory and there's not enough physical memory available for the configured amounts.

Comment: Yes but is the DB2 instance also 64 bit?

Comment: DB2 is 32 bit
Is it the Unreserved memory left in set  : 61014016 bytes.
the amount that was unavailable?

Comment: You need to monitor the heap usage, as [described here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000276.html), and keep adjusting the heap size.